# XMLWriter is not loading in braintree

Tags: php, payment, braintree, lumen, xmlwriter

I'm using braintree to accept payments on my website. But when I try to open a view to make a purchase I get this error:

> Exception in Braintree.php line 20:
>   The Braintree library requires the xmlwriter extension.

and this is my Braintree.php file:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Braintree PHP Library
 * Creates class_aliases for old class names replaced by PSR-4 Namespaces
 *
 * @copyright  2015 Braintree, a division of PayPal, Inc.
 */

require_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
    throw new Braintree_Exception('PHP version >= 5.4.0 required');
}


function requireDependencies() {
    $requiredExtensions = ['xmlwriter', 'openssl', 'dom', 'hash', 'curl'];
    foreach ($requiredExtensions AS $ext) {
        if (!extension_loaded($ext)) {
            throw new Braintree_Exception('The Braintree library requires the ' . $ext . ' extension.');
        }
    }
}

requireDependencies();
```

I already checked that xmlwriter and libxml are enabled and installed on my project and everything is settled up. So I don't know what else to do. Any idea of why is this happening?

Any help is very apreciatted :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, make sure XMLWriter PHP modules are installed

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml`

`php -i | grep "xml"`

This should display the line `xmlwriter`

Check your error log `sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log`

If any errors are `failed to open stream`, check that your paths are correct.

Error messages should give you more direction.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much :)

Comment: And how can I check the paths? I mean, there are a lot of directories. Where are all the extensions?

Comment: @G.Rocha when you are visiting your `braintree.php` file, does this generate an error in your server log?

What setup are you using? (I just assumed nginx in my answer)

Comment: if running apache, make sure you restart the webserver `sudo service apache2 restart` so the changes are realized.